# Sharepoint Health Analyzer 404 errors

Tags: sharepoint

I have recently taken over a new installation of Sharepoint 2013, comprising of a database server, two app servers hosting the central admin site and two web servers. The central admin site and other site collections are accessed using AAMs, with the pairs of servers bound using Network Load Balancing.

If I follow the link on the Central Administration homepage from the banner "The Sharepoint Health Analyzer has detected some critical issues that require your attention" (which loads `http://servername/Lists/HealthReports/AllItems.aspx`), rather than showing the status of the jobs I only see a blank page, though the menu structure on the left is still valid.

When using Central Administration and trying to follow the link Monitoring > Review Problems and Solutions I get a 404 at the page `http://servername/Lists/HealthReports`.

I can view the job definitions and statuses without issue and trigger the jobs using Powershell, so it looks as though the page content required to display the ../HealthReports/.. pages is missing/broken. Does anyone have any ideas on how I might repopulate it or further investigate the issue? I'm not that familiar with Sharepoint and don't know exactly what steps were taken to build this farm.

I have tried rebuilding the Central Administration website using the Sharepoint Configuration Wizard but the issue persists, as it does if I run a "repair" install from the installation CD.

Edit: I have just discovered `http://servername/searchfarmdashboard.aspx` also shows a blank page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never managed to find a good solution for this, so as there was little content on the site, I ended up creating a new farm and backing up/restoring the data into the new one.